# How does one apply multiple beamsplitters to a covariance matrix in the covariance matrix (2nd moments) formalism?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, bosons

I would like to propagate a two-mode squeezed vacuum state through a collection of beamsplitters. I'd like to represent this in the second moments, that is, the covariance formalism such as used in quantum information, so that I start with a covariance matrix, $\gamma$ and apply the many beamsplitter symplectic matrices, $S_1, S_2, S_3, ...$.
If I apply $S_1$ first, $\gamma_1=S_1^T\gamma S_1$, this of course makes $\gamma_1$ a diagonal matrix, so that I think it would then be improper to apply $S_2$. What is the appropriate way to do this in order to get a physically correct final covariance matrix?

More specifically, suppose we have the following (in xp-order):

$$\gamma = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
2\mu+1 & 0 & 0 & 2\sqrt{\mu(\mu+1)} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-2\sqrt{\mu(\mu+1)} & 0 & 0 & 2\mu+1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right)^{⊕2}$$, where ⊕2 is to give the p-block for gamma
Then, say we have two beamsplitter matrices:
$$S_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\sqrt{\eta} & \sqrt{1-\eta} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-\sqrt{1-\eta} & \sqrt{\eta} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{\eta} & 0 & \sqrt{1-\eta}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{1-\eta} & 0 & \sqrt{\eta}\\
\end{array}\right)^{⊕2}$$
$$S_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\sqrt{t} & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{1-t} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{t} & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{1-t} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{t} & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{1-t}\\
-\sqrt{1-t} & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{t} & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\sqrt{1-t} & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{t} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\sqrt{1-t} & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{t}\\
\end{array}\right)^{⊕2}$$

So the question put more succinctly is:
$\gamma_{final}=(S_2^T(S_1^T \gamma S_1) S_2)\\$
or
$\gamma_{final}=(S_2^T S_1^T (\gamma) S_1 S_2)$
or
something else?

Comment: Why is $\gamma_1$ diagonal? Just multiply all the $S$!

Comment: The covariance matrix is a symmetric positive-definite matrix and the beamsplitter matrices are symplectic. By Williamson's Theorem, $S_1$ as applied above will diagonalize $\gamma$ (Williamson normal mode form). Or are you saying to multiply the $S$ matrices all together, and then apply to $\gamma$?

Comment: Well, to be fair, you had not specified $\gamma$ and $S$!

Comment: True, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\gamma_\mathrm{final}$ is exactly what you specify:
$$
\gamma_{\mathrm{final}} = S_2^TS_1^T\gamma S_1 S_2 = S^T \gamma S\ ,
$$
with $S=S_1S_2$.

This is evident since under $S$, $\gamma$ transforms as $\gamma\mapsto S^T\gamma S$. If you apply two such maps, you get their concatenation.  Where you put your brackets does not matter, as matrix multiplication is associative.